# Lnd invoice lookup

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, invoices

I am trying to get single invoice with `GET /v2/invoices/lookup` endpoint on LND REST API by its id as documented here: https://api.lightning.community/?javascript#v2-invoices-lookup. But whatever I do I get `"Not found"` response. How does one call this endpoint? I tried `/v2/invoices/lookup?set_id={id}` and add `set_id` to the request body and call it without parameters at all.

Moreover it is not documented what `set_id` param actually is. I supose it is same incremental id as is `add_index` in response of `POST /v1/invoices` endpoint. Is that true?

I know about `GET /v1/invoice/{r_hash_str}` endpoint but I would like to use the other because I prefer using integer id over long hash.

One more, it is true that `r_hash` is always 44 symbols long or is it variable?